# python- access to variables given conditions

Tags: python, list

I'm an R user, so I'm accustom to use data frames an access data using conditions in the data[data$variable=='condition',] way.
I'm trying to write a simple probabilistic neural network example in python. 
If my data is:

```
data = {'o' : [(0.2, 0.5), (0.5, 0.7)],
        'x' : [(0.8, 0.8), (0.4, 0.5)],
        'i' : [(0.8, 0.5), (0.6, 0.3), (0.3, 0.2)]}
```

and I want to classify a new record:

```
nuevo=(0.2, 0.6)
```

I managed to write the following code that creates a sort of table (list of lists) with every print to see whats going on...

```
kk=[]

def g (data, nuevo):

    for k in data:
        print(k)        
        j=-1
        for i in data[k]:         
            j=j+1
            print(i)        
            print(i[0])
            print(i[1])
            kk.append([k,i,math.e ** (-1 *((nuevo[0] - i[0]) ** 2 + (nuevo[1] - i[1]) ** 2) / ((2 * (0.1 ** 2))))])
            print(kk[j])

g(data, nuevo)
```

At the end I have the kk list of lists and I need to select the max of each o, x and i. And then select the one that has the max value.

I tried something like `kk[kk[][0]=='o']` to get all the elements that have an 'o' but I get the wrong result. This must be pretty simple but I'm not being able to see it in a simpler way (i don't want to use a loop).

Comment: Python's built-in structures aren't set up to work that way.  They don't enforce a tabular structure, so Python doesn't, for instance, know or care whether all the "columns" in your structure even have the same length.  Likewise, vectorized operations (without a loop) aren't possible because there's no requirement that all the values you're storing have the same type.  If you want to do R-style stuff, I recommend you look at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, which provides data structures similar to R's vectors and dataframes.

Comment: ok, thanks. but if you have to solve it with the basics, how would you do this? maybe taking advantage of the loops that form the kk lists?

Comment: @GabrielaPlantie you might be able to use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a condition to get what you want. Simple example: `[x for x in range(100) if x % 2 == 0]`

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do. If you want to filter a list to get only the values satisfying a certain predicate, you can user the `filter` function.

Comment: @GabrielaPlantie: You can't do it with the basics without loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can streamline a bit your function `g` using a *list comprehension*

```
def g(d,n):
    return [[k,i,exp(-50*((n[0]-i[0])**2+(n[1]-i[1])**2))] for k in d for i in d[k]]
```

I dare say that using a function to modify a global data structure is not always the best solution possible...

That said, you want to choose the maximum proximity for each category, so

```
def max_p(d, p):
    return [max((x for x in p if x[0]==k), key=lambda x: x[2]) for k in d]
```

again, list comprehension (a list element for each key `k` in your data dictionary `d`) and a new thing, a *generator expression*, that is the part `(x for x in p if x[0]==k)`; the generator expression gives, an element each time, all the elements in the list of computed proximities to the `max` builtin function.

The second argument of the `max` function is a function that computes the sorting key, here `key=lambda x: x[2])` is a function, defined on the spot using the `lambda` syntax, that returns the inner element with index 2.

```
In [49]: data = {'o' : [(0.2, 0.5), (0.5, 0.7)],
        'x' : [(0.8, 0.8), (0.4, 0.5)],
        'i' : [(0.8, 0.5), (0.6, 0.3), (0.3, 0.2)]}

In [50]: nuevo = (0.2, 0.6)

In [51]: def g(d,n):
    return [[k,i,exp(-50*((n[0]-i[0])**2+(n[1]-i[1])**2))] for k in d for i in d[k]]
   ....: 

In [52]: def max_p(d, p):
    return [max((x for x in p if x[0]==k), key=lambda x: x[2]) for k in d]
   ....: 

In [53]: max_p(data, g(data, nuevo))
Out[53]: 
[['i', (0.3, 0.2), 0.00020346836901064417],
 ['x', (0.4, 0.5), 0.0820849986238988],
 ['o', (0.2, 0.5), 0.6065306597126335]]

In [54]: max(max_p(data, g(data, nuevo)), key=lambda x: x[2])
Out[54]: ['o', (0.2, 0.5), 0.6065306597126335]

In [55]:
```

That said, you may better introduce yourself to the `numpy` module that

1. introduces true arrays and define array optimized functions and operators,
2. introduces the opportunity of indexing the arrays using Boolean expressions (that is, what you do want eventually...)

Another option is the `pandas` module, but others have already mentioned that...